# Css3 Blurring text on transform scale even it's not even part of the animating block

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

It's the first time that I have experienced the blurring of text after transform scaling an icon or atleast a text adjacent to another text/paragraph.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fddmfqn6/.

Here is the markup

```
<div class="b-site__body">
    <div class="b-bigass-header">
         <h1 class="b-bigass-header__title">I am <span class="b-bigass-title_emp">Fooo</span></h1>

        <!-- /.b-bigass-header__title -->
         <h3 class="b-bigass-header__subtitle b-bigass-spaced--full b-bigass-upper">something jibberish</h3>

        <!-- /.b-bigass-header__subtitle -->
        <div class="b-bigass-social"> <a href="//a"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">A</span></a>
 <a href="//b"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">B</span></a>
 <a href="//c"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">C</span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.b-bigass-header -->
</div>
```

And here is the css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

a, a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.b-site__body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.b-bigass-header {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.b-bigass-social {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.b-bigass-social a {
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 1.33333333em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
}
.b-bigass-social a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.b-bigass-social__icon {
    transition: transform 250ms ease, color 250ms linear;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    display: block;
}
.b-bigass-social a:hover .b-bigass-social__icon {
    color: #03a9f4;
    transition: transform 250ms ease;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I do not know why this is happening when the texts are not even part of the animating (transforming) block, it's just its sibling.

Comment: Tried on IE and FF, I can't see any blurring effect anywhere? Maybe browser incompatibility ?

Comment: try removing `translate` and positioning [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fddmfqn6/1/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes your fiddle definitely works, but I can't arguably settle with the solution, since I need the `header` to be centered, probably I'll try different technique for aligning..

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue yeah, it happened on chrome..

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fddmfqn6/2/

use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` technique to `vertical-align middle`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
}
a,
a:link,
a:active,
a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
.b-site__body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.b-bigass-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.b-bigass-social {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.b-bigass-social a {
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 1.33333333em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}
.b-bigass-social a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.b-bigass-social__icon {
  transition: transform 250ms ease, color 250ms linear;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  display: block;
}
.b-bigass-social a:hover .b-bigass-social__icon {
  color: #03a9f4;
  transition: transform 250ms ease;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="b-site__body">
  <div class="b-bigass-header">
    <h1 class="b-bigass-header__title">I am <span class="b-bigass-title_emp">Fooo</span></h1>

    <!-- /.b-bigass-header__title -->
    <h3 class="b-bigass-header__subtitle b-bigass-spaced--full b-bigass-upper">something jibberish</h3>

    <!-- /.b-bigass-header__subtitle -->
    <div class="b-bigass-social"> <a href="//a"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">A</span></a>
      <a href="//b"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">B</span></a>
      <a href="//c"><span class="b-bigass-social__icon">C</span></a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.b-bigass-header -->
</div>
```